# Is there a way to adjust the linespacing in a TableGrob in R, when you have wrapped a string to fit in a cell?

Tags: r, string, gridextra

I'm trying to reduce the linespacing in cells where I have long character strings.

```
library(gridExtra)
Table <- data.frame(Model = c("Long names bla bla", "Long name bla bla 2"))
Table[,"Model"] <- sapply(Table[,"Model"] , function(x) paste(strwrap(x, width = 10),  collapse="\n"))
grid.arrange(tableGrob(Table))
```

See example code output here.
[Linespacing looks about 1.5 pt I would like it to be 1 pt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xee5n.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get.gpar()$lineheight 
# 1.2 default
mytheme <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(lineheight=1)))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tableGrob(Table, theme = mytheme))
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question